# Apache not directing the routes defined in laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, virtualhost

I was working with Laravel and when I use the artisan commands to serve, my site works perfectly. But if I open my site through the virtual host in my apache then the basic routes in the PHP application gives me a not found error. I tried solving this by enabling the rewrite mod which was already enabled. I think that my site still should work since it is working when I use the artisan way of development. 
What may be the problem? Also is the directory tag/initiative necessary for virtual host creation?

P.S. My /var/www contains symlink of the actual folder where I develop using artisan

Below is my .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName parkinghost
ServerAlias www.parkinghost.com
ServerAlias *.parkinghost.com
ServerAdmin info@parkinghost.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/parkingLaravel/public
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have `Option FollowSymLinks` enabled in your apache config? My apache-fu is rusting, but maybe that bites you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open the apache2.conf file and find "Allow Override None". Please change to "Allow Override All" in / directory or in /var/www/html directory tag code area. Your issue will be solved then.